# How do I access a package's info manual?

Tags: package, use-package, info

I installed magit, and it appears to have come with documentation I can access in info-mode:

```
> cd ~/emacs.d/elpa
> ls -1 magit-2.8.0/{dir,*.info*}
magit-2.8.0/dir
magit-2.8.0/magit.info
magit-2.8.0/magit.info-1
magit-2.8.0/magit.info-2
```

But when I run `info` in emacs, I don't see any entry for Magit in the directory. I've also tried running `info-apropos` to search for magit, and found nothing. What do I need to do to get it to show up?

I'm using `use-package`, if that's significant:

```
(use-package magit
  :load-path ("elpa/magit-2.8.0"
              "elpa/with-editor-2.5.2"
              "elpa/git-commit-2.8.0"
              "elpa/magit-popup-2.8.0")
  :config
  (setq vc-handled-backends (delq 'Git vc-handled-backends)))
```

I'm also using the newest version of Emacs I could find, GNU Emacs 25.1.1

*However*, I've intentionally avoided calling `package-initialize` in my init.el except as needed (e.g. when installing new packages), which is why I'm specifying a load-path in the `use-package` declaration above. Maybe that's related; I'm pretty sure `package-initialize` populates the load-path so packages can be found -- does it also populate `Info-directory-list`?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer, but I seem to recall often having this problem in the distant past, while with modern emacsen, new packages automagically get an entry in the top level Info node. I am not sure by what mechanism … but anyway, is your emacs an old one?

Comment: Yes, let us know what Emacs version you have, as the package system has changed quite a bit over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the directory containing the `*.info` files to `Info-directory-list`, using `add-to-list`.

If it provides an Info manual, the package should have taken care of this for you.  Node [Multi-File Packages](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Multi_002dfile-Packages.html) of the Elisp manual says this:

> If the content directory contains a file named `dir`, this is assumed
>   to be an Info directory file made with `install-info`.  *Note Invoking
>   install-info: (texinfo)Invoking install-info.  The relevant Info files
>   should also be present in the content directory.  In this case, Emacs
>   will automatically add the content directory to **`Info-directory-list`**
>   when the package is activated.

Comment: This worked. I ended up adding this to the `:config` section of my `use-package` declaration: `(eval-after-load 'info '(add-to-list 'Info-additional-directory-list "~/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-2.8.0/"))`

Comment: @ivan: note that this *should not* be necessary since package.el should do that for you when `package-initialize` is called.  Of course, if you use `use-package`, maybe you're preventing package.el from doing its job, in which case you're s.o.l.

Comment: Are there examples of any ELPA/MELPA packages that do this properly? (Preferably MELPA, to be perfectly honest.)